# PHP News Via Modal

Tags: php, jquery

i'm currently working on a project to improve my PHP/SQL skills.
So basically i want to make it so you click on the news title opens a modal that shows the news content, this is what i currently have and it isn't working.
Also sorry for my english, I'm dutch.

```
$newssql = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 4");
                 while($row = $newssql ->fetch())
                 {
                 $id = $row['ID'];
                 $title = $row['title'];
                 $content = $row['content'];
                 $autor = $row['author'];
                 echo '
                 <a  data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$id.'" data-target="#modal-3">
                     <div class="inbox-item">
                         <p class="inbox-item-author">'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</p>
                         <p class="inbox-item-text">'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</p>
                         <p class="inbox-item-date">'.date("m/d/y" ,$row['date']).'</p>
                     </div>
                 </a>
                 ';
                 }
```

//Modal

```
                       <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modal-label-3" class="modal fade"
 id="modal-3" role="modal" style="display: none;" tabindex="-1">
     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
                 <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss=
                 "modal" type="button">×</button>

                 <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-label-3">NEWS</h4>
             </div>


             <div class="modal-body">
                 <?php echo htmlspecialchars($content); ?>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

//jQuery

```
    <script>
     $('button[data-target="#modal-3"]').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var j = $(this).attr('data-id');
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I can see,

```
<script>
 $('button[data-target="#modal-3"]').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var j = $(this).attr('data-id');
});
</script>
```

jquery will detect a click event from a button where as you stated

```
echo '
             <a  data-toggle="modal" data-id="'.$id.'" data-target="#modal-3">
                 <div class="inbox-item">
                     <p class="inbox-item-author">'.htmlspecialchars($title).'</p>
                     <p class="inbox-item-text">'.htmlspecialchars($content).'</p>
                     <p class="inbox-item-date">'.date("m/d/y" ,$row['date']).'</p>
                 </div>
             </a>
             ';
```

it's on an `<a>` tag which is not a button.

Comment: Read the above comment^ @Aron Quiray